# MySQL - Compare Values from Ajax array and DELETE them IF NOT in TABLE

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ajax, arrays

With a POST METHOD `$tab_tuto_sauvegarde = $_POST['tableau_valeurs_modifiees'];` a Ajax request returns to me this informations :

```
[Mots_cles_supprimes] => Array
(
    [0] => jambon
    [1] => rap
    [2] => tomate
)
```

I have these tables

```
TABLE 1 named 'Mots_cles'

|  mots_cles |
_____________
| jambon     |
|  rap       |
|  tomate    |

TABLE 2 named 'Mots_cles_et_tutoriels'

|  id_tutoriel ||  mots_cles  |
______________________________
| ID1          || rap         |
| ID1          || rap         |
| ID2          || tomate      |
| ID2          || rap         |
| ID2          || tomate      |
```

First I `DELETE` each `[index]` from `tableau_valeurs_modifiees.['Mots_cles_supprimes']` in the `TABLE 2` like this :

```
if (isset ($tab_tuto_sauvegarde['Mots_cles_supprimes'])){
$sql_Mots_cles_id_tutoriel = "";
foreach($tab_tuto_sauvegarde['Mots_cles_supprimes'] as $index => $valeur){
    $sql_Mots_cles_id_tutoriel .= "('$id_tutoriel', '$valeur'), ";      
}
if($sql_Mots_cles_id_tutoriel !== ""){
    $sql_Mots_cles_id_tutoriel = substr($sql_Mots_cles_id_tutoriel, 0, -2); // Supprime la ',' à la fin de la chaine de caractere
    mysqli_query($BDD_connect, "DELETE FROM Mots_cles_et_tutoriels WHERE (id_tutoriel, mots_cles) IN (".$sql_Mots_cles_id_tutoriel.")");
```

It works good !

But then, what I need is for each `[index]` of `tableau_valeurs_modifiees.['Mots_cles_supprimes']` (here : "jambon", "rap" and "tomate") compare these words to the `TABLE 2` and if not exist in this `TABLE 2`, `DELETE` them in the `TABLE 1`

I think I have the end of the code (DELETE in the TABLE 1 each word) but it miss me the condition IF these words are not exist in TABLE 1...

```
$stmt_mot_a_sup = mysqli_prepare($BDD_connect, "DELETE FROM Mots_cles SET mots_cles = ? ");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt_mot_a_sup, "s", $mot_a_sup);
    foreach ($tab_tuto_sauvegarde['Mots_cles_supprimes'] as $Mots_cles_supprimes) {
        $mot_a_sup = $Mots_cles_supprimes;
        mysqli_execute($stmt_mot_a_sup);
    }
```

I don't know and where put the condition IF NOT EXIST IN TABLE 2 > DELETE IN TABLE 1 ... ?

thanks !

---

### **EDIT - MORE INFORMATIONS**

Here are the two tables :

1/ Table "Mots_cles" which contains all database of keywords
[image: Table 'Mots_cles]

2/ Table "Mots_cles_et_tutoriels" wich countains keywords belonging to each id_tutorial
[image: Table "Mots_cles_et_tutoriels"]

My POST METHOD `$tab_tuto_sauvegarde = $_POST['tableau_valeurs_modifiees'];` returns to me :

1/ an ID (a number) like `90` or `92` or whatever ... corresponding to a tutorial

2/ several words to delete in the table 'Mots_cles_et_tutoriel' corresponding to the ID returns to me

So, first I delete this several words in the table 'Mots_cles_et_tutoriel' like this :

```
if (isset ($tab_tuto_sauvegarde['Mots_cles_supprimes'])){
$sql_Mots_cles_id_tutoriel = "";
foreach($tab_tuto_sauvegarde['Mots_cles_supprimes'] as $index => $valeur){
    $sql_Mots_cles_id_tutoriel .= "('$id_tutoriel', '$valeur'), ";      
}
if($sql_Mots_cles_id_tutoriel !== ""){
    $sql_Mots_cles_id_tutoriel = substr($sql_Mots_cles_id_tutoriel, 0, -2); // Supprime la ',' à la fin de la chaine de caractere
    mysqli_query($BDD_connect, "DELETE FROM Mots_cles_et_tutoriels WHERE (id_tutoriel, mots_cles) IN (".$sql_Mots_cles_id_tutoriel.")");
```

And then, what I need is, if this deleted words no longer exist in the Table "Mots_cles_et_tutoriels" (regardless the id...), I need to delete also in table "Mots_cles" (delete these words in all database).

For example, if my POST Method returns to me this :

```
id_tutoriel => 92

[Mots_cles_supprimes] => Array
(
    [0] => rap
    [1] => tyty
    [2] => er6
    [3] => Kawasaki
)
```

In the Table  "Mots_cles_et_tutoriels" I delete `"rap"`, `"tyty"`, `"er6"` and `"kawasaki"` where "id_tutoriel" = `92`

And I would like to delete in the Table "Mots_cles" just words `"er6"` and `"kawasaki"` because just after have been deleted, they no more exist in table "Mots_cles_et_tutoriels" unlike `"rap"`and `"tyty"` which are already existing in table "Mots_cles_et_tutoriels".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first: it's really hard to read mixed english and french :-) but i think i got it.

```
DELETE FROM TABLE_1 t1 
WHERE t1.mots_cles not in (
    SELECT t2.mots_cles FROM TABLE_2 t2
)
```

This simple query says that you want to delete every row in TABLE_1 which has no concurrent value row in TABLE_2. For bigger databases, this should be optimized.

Comment: one point for french :p ...! otherwise, I already used this method and it works but as you said, for a bigger databases, this should be optimized. In a near future, TABLE 1 and TABLE 2 will have thousands words in database... and at each request (thousands by hours may be more...) I can't use  computer server to compare all TABLE 1 and all  TABLE 2 ... That's why I just need to compare words from Ajax Array.

Comment: Can you please post your database layout (at least your indices). Without this i cannot give a good answer :)

Comment: Why are you using the first table? Maybe it's better to use a DISTINCT mots_cles on the second one. See http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp

Comment: Because before all of that, client create a web page with differents informations with this existing database of keywords. Then when client validate all of his informations, keywords that he selected are attributed with id of the page. But in my case I don't think that DISTINCT is useful...